# Batch Scripting -- Creating variables based on input

Tags: loops, batch-file, dynamic-variables

I am trying to use batch scripting to create and assign variables dynamically based on a space separated list of computer names.

The computer names are assigned to %hosts% (which are pulled from another file in the production script). What I am trying to accomplish is to count the number of hosts that were pulled in (they are separated by spaces), then assign each one to a variable that contains a number relating to the order the hosts are listed.

Here is the code snippet:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET hosts=10.10.0.0 192.168.0.0 W2K3-Server
SET /a counter=0

FOR %%I IN (%hosts%) DO (
    SET /a counter+=1
)

echo Total= !counter!

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,!counter!) DO (
    FOR %%I in (%hosts%) DO (
        IF [!host%%A!]==[] SET host%%A=%%I
        echo host%%A= !host%%A!
    )
)

endlocal
```

The output of this script is:

```
Total= 3
host1= 10.10.0.0
host1= 10.10.0.0
host1= 10.10.0.0
host2= 10.10.0.0
host2= 10.10.0.0
host2= 10.10.0.0
host3= 10.10.0.0
host3= 10.10.0.0
host3= 10.10.0.0
```

The results I would like to see is:

```
Total= 3
host1= 10.10.0.0
host2= 192.168.0.0
host3= W2K3-Server
```

I know why I am getting the first result. There is no checking to see if a condition is met. In this case, the condition would be setting one of the hosts as a variable. I need to know how to step out of the "FOR %%I in (%hosts%)" section of the loop once a variable has been set.

Is this possible in batch? This piece is not critical to the project I am working on, but it would add value by opening up some new possibilities in other areas of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET hosts=10.10.0.0 192.168.0.0 W2K3-Server
SET /a counter=0

FOR %%I IN (%hosts%) DO (
    SET /a counter+=1
    IF [!host%%I!]==[] SET host!counter!=%%I
)

echo Total= !counter!

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,!counter!) DO (
    echo host%%A= !host%%A!
)

endlocal
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET hosts=10.10.0.0 192.168.0.0 W2K3-Server
SET /a counter=0

FOR %%I IN (%hosts%) DO (
    SET /a counter+=1
    set host!counter!=%%I
)

echo Total= !counter!

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,!counter!) DO (
  echo host%%A = !host%%A!
)

endlocal
```

Comment: This answer was posted around the same time as George's answer and is pretty close to the same code. Thanks for the time spent to help!